# Hot to retrieve user information from a document library in Sharepoint 2010 using c#

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-foundation, development, approval

I'm working on an approval workflow where when a user uploads a document, he assigns the task to the approver while creating a document, like:

[image]

Now I'm trying to fetch the approver's details in my code so that I can assign a task and send an email notification to the approver for the task assigned.

```
if (workflowProperties.Item["Approver"] != null)
        {
            this._approver = workflowProperties.Item["Approver"].ToString();
        }
```

But I don't know if that's the correct way and how do I get all the user information and email so that I can assign a task to the user?

**Note:** I tried with this but the task is not assigned to the intended user. No task however is assigned when I upload a document. Please suggest what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance.